# MySQL "where" condition not returning the right data

Tags: mysql

Test table:

```
pupil_id  |   test|value
10001     |     10|    1
10001     |     11|    2
10002     |     12|    0
10002     |     13|    1
10003     |     14|    0
10003     |     15|    2
```

Here I want to filter only pupils that didn't have ever the value 2, so from this example it means that I want only to see student with id 10002 because he never had a value 2.

I tried with:

```
JOIN test ON pupils.pupil_id=test.pupil_id AND value <> 2
```

but I don't get the data I want because MySQL returns me also pupils with id's that have had the value 2, for example:

```
pupil_id  |   test|value
10001     |     10|    1
10001     |     11|    2
10002     |     12|    0
10002     |     13|    1
10003     |     14|    0
10003     |     15|    2
```

With that `WHERE` condition it returns 10001, 10002, 10003, so it returns pupils that have value 2 but I want only pupils that didn't ever have the value 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here i want to filter only students that didn't have ever the status=2

Couple off possible queries.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT 
 pupil_id
FROM 
 table
GROUP BY 
 pupil_id
HAVING NOT SUM(value= 2)
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT 
 pupil_id
FROM
 table 
WHERE
 pupil_id NOT IN(
   SELECT 
     pupil_id
   FROM 
     table
   WHERE
    value = 2
 )
```

Comment: Hi @Raymond i think Query 1 it will not give the correct result  cuz if we have student_id with test_status  3 and 2 it will be in result but he have 2 in test_status

Comment: @NigHamza i know for a fact that query 1 should work just fine.. I think you don't know how `HAVING NOT SUM(test_status = 2)` works in combination with the `GROUP BY`. so check this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/27SuaGjL3SKfxhvqRRWUdd/1

Comment: Thank you for example yeh i see i didnt see SUM(test_status = 2) the number 2

Comment: @RaymondNijland thaaanks alooot fella , it worked like a charm!

Comment: if the answer worked consider accepting the answer read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work or https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers @Maximilian

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry that i didn't accept earlier but i wasn't familiarized with it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi query see code bellow :

```
 select pupil_id,test,value from Table1 
where  pupil_id not in (select pupil_id from Table1 where value=2)
```

Here a sqlfiddel :https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/27SuaGjL3SKfxhvqRRWUdd/4

Comment: @Maximilian if this answer work for you you can accepeted and vote up for helping other people

Comment: in my case it didn't work only the first answer did fit

Comment: and why you didnt accepte the answer its good helping other to know where is the right answer

Comment: I tried but it says that I don't have reputation so i guess i need to have 3+ votes or 5+ on a post then I can vote up :s

Comment: here how you accepte : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: and i think myanswe is correct you can check the sqlfiddel example

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE` clause.

```
LEFT JOIN test
  ON pupils.pupil_id=test.pupil_id
    AND test.value= 2 
 WHERE test.pupil is null
```